# Find rows that match between two unequal matrices (one is subset of anotherusing two columns of data)

Tags: matlab, match

I have tried the code below to find matches, but I have gotten the error that matrix dimensions must agree.

```
mat = [ 8 5; 4 3; 3 5]
mat2 = [2 3; 2 3; 4 3; 4 3]

for i=1:size(mat,1)
    idx= find(mat2(:,1) == mat(i,1)& mat2(:,2) == mat(i,2)); 
end
idx= find(mat2(:,1) == mat(:,1))
```

I need to find rows that match between two unequal matrices using two columns of data (x&y coordinates for example) in order to append a column of data to the correct rows in the larger matrix. I basically need to find the rows in the larger matrix where values match those values in the smaller matrix so that the column of data from the smaller matrix can be appended to the correct row.

Comment: Not sure about the last part of the request, could you clarify that?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

```
>> [c,imat,imat2] = intersect( mat, mat2, 'rows')
c =
     4     3
imat =
     2
imat2 =
     4
```

c are the rows that match. 
imat are the indices of the matching rows in mat 
imat2 are the indices of the matching rows in mat2

Comment: brechmos...regarding the last part...I am trying to append a column of data from the smaller subset matrix to the larger matrix. I am using unique lat/long data from both matrices to find the rows to append that data